# Localhost image won't show on Xamarin Android emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I'm trying to reference an image in localhost in my Xamarin project but the image won't show. When the Android emulator starts up the screen is blank.

**Xaml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp.MyView">
  <ContentView.Content>

      <StackLayout>

            <Image x:Name="TheImage"></Image>

      </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**Server side code**

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TheImage.Source = new UriImageSource
    {
        Uri = new Uri("https://localhost/images/someImage.png")
    };

}
```

If I use a URL for an image on a public website then it works okay so it must me something to do with localhost.

Comment: @SushiHangover Great, it worked. Put it up as the answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Localhost` is the emulator itself as it is a complete (Linux) OS and localhost is its "loopback adapter", not your PC.

Depending on the Android emulator you are are using, you can use **`10.0.2.2`** to reach a service on the PC that is hosting the emulator.